# Memory level for Ceph logs. What's this for?

Tags: ceph, debug

I want to increase the logging level of some OSDs, but I don't understand what the memory level is for. I didn't find an exact explanation in the [documentation](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/troubleshooting/log-and-debug/). Is there a need to increase this level? OSD logs are written in rsyslog.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I understand that this is the level of logs directly stored in memory and they can be read in the log file after the command is executed:

```
ceph daemon osd.X log dump
```